# SQL Delete from DataGridView is not happening

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a DataGridView that has delete enabled, but it never happens. The whole grid disappears (multiple rows), but the delete for the row I click never happens.

I can run the sql statement manually in sql management studio and it works just fine, but never seems to run from the web page.

i'm not sure where to go from here, I haven't had an issue like this from a GridView before.

SqlDataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceVisitors" runat="server" ConnectionString="constring" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [RegisteredVisitors] WHERE [PK] = @PK UPDATE [dbo].[Users] SET [NumberOfVisitors] = (SELECT [NumberOfVisitors] FROM [dbo].[NumberOfVisitors] WHERE [ResidentName] = @ResidentName) -1 WHERE [ResidentName] = @ResidentName" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [RegisteredVisitors] ([ResidentName], [ResidentAddress], [VisitorCode], [VisitorName]) VALUES (@ResidentName, @ResidentAddress, @VisitorCode, @VisitorName)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [RegisteredVisitors] WHERE ([ResidentName] = @ResidentName)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [RegisteredVisitors] SET [ResidentName] = @ResidentName, [ResidentAddress] = @ResidentAddress, [VisitorCode] = @VisitorCode, [VisitorName] = @VisitorName WHERE [PK] = @PK" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="PK" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ResidentName" Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ResidentName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ResidentAddress" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="VisitorCode" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="VisitorName" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtboxSelectedResident" Name="ResidentName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="ResidentName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ResidentAddress" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="VisitorCode" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="VisitorName" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PK" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="DataGridViewVisitors" runat="server" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceVisitors" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, you just missed **;** in DeleteCommand. Everything written inside command will be executed in a single go. So to separate out delete and update query you need ;.

```
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [RegisteredVisitors] WHERE [PK] = @PK; UPDATE [dbo].[Users] SET [NumberOfVisitors] = (SELECT [NumberOfVisitors] FROM [dbo].[NumberOfVisitors] WHERE [ResidentName] = @ResidentName) -1 WHERE [ResidentName] = @ResidentName"
```

Comment: Separation is not the answer, removal of the second statement altogether is.

Comment: I need that other statement.

Comment: I did try, now all of a sudden its telling me i have to declare my parameters. which is confusing because you can see, they are there.

Comment: It should be working. Can't say what's going wrong. Another thing you could try with Stored Procedure. Create a SP with delete command query and use this. DeleteCommand="YourStoredProc"      
  DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure"

Comment: Agreed, stored procedure is better way to go if you need to run multiple statements. I wonder if the parser only considers the first statement. What parameters exactly is it complaining about? All, or just the one from the UPDATE statement?

Comment: The parameters @ PK and @ ResidentName only from the delete statement